# AWS OpsWorks SSH Connect directly permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-opsworks

From AWS OpsWorks SSH instructions, connect directly section (ssh from Terminal):

> Directly connect to the instance using your terminal application.
>   ssh://foobar@1.2.3.4

I just copied the ssh url and tried but got permission denied:

```
> ssh ssh://foobar@1.2.3.4
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not need to specify the protocol, just do:

```
ssh foobar@1.2.3.4
```